# number base conversion recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I have to create a recursive method to convert base 10 numbers to any base numbers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJMmm.jpg

- If base is 2 then prefix the string with "0b"
- If base is 16 then prefix the string with "0x"
- If base is 10 then no prefix (or postfix)
- in all other cases postfix the string with the base in square brackets

Examples:

- If value is 212 and base is 2 then the method returns "0b11010100"
- If value is 212 and base is 10 then the method returns "212"
- If value is 212 and base is 12 then the method returns "119 [base 12]"
- If value is 212 and base is 20 then the method returns "AC [base 20]"
- If value is 212 and base is 16 then the method returns "0xD4"
- If value is 212 and base is 60 then the method returns "3.32 [base 60]"

My problem is with the "in all other cases postfix the string with the base in square brackets" bit. I cannot figure it out. Could you help, please?

Here is my general solution:

```
public class NaturalNumber {
private int value;

public NaturalNumber(int value){
    this.value = value;
}

public void setValue(int value){
    this.value = value;
}

public int getValue(){
    return value;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return Integer.toString(value);
}

public String getValueBase(int base){
    return getValueBase(value, base);
}

public static String getValueBase(int value, int base){
    int quotient = value / base;
    int remainder = value % base;
    char ch = (char)(remainder+55);



    if(quotient <= 0) { 
        if(remainder >= 10 && remainder <= 36){
            if(base==16)
                return "0x" + ch; 
            return "" + ch; 
        }
        else {

            if(base==2)
                return "0b" + remainder;
            if(base==16)
                return "0x" + remainder;
            return "" + remainder;
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if(base > 36){
            return getValueBase(quotient, base) + "." + remainder;
        }
        if(remainder >= 10 && remainder <= 36){
            return getValueBase(quotient, base) + ch; 
        }
        return getValueBase(quotient, base) + remainder;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NaturalNumber n = new NaturalNumber(68654332);
    System.out.println(n.getValueBase(38));
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: My problem is with adding [base] at the end. Could you help, please?

Comment: Still not a question.

Comment: I need to add string "[base x]" at the end of conversion result in my recursive method. This what I cannot figure out and need some help with. Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Does it need to be appended inside the recursive method? Why not in `getValue(int)` or in `main()`?

Comment: yes, in the recursive method. it is fairly easy otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about this wrong, this does not have to be done in a recursive loop. Though if you pass the number-base all the way through the loop you can add it to the end when you hit the base-case of the loop. Else you will have to have to pass some type of parameter (boolean) that is only true in the first call of the function.

```
public String getValueBase(int base){
        switch (base){
            case 2:
                return "0b" + getValueBase(value, base) ;
            case 10:
                return "0x" + getValueBase(value, base) ;
            default:
                return getValueBase(value, base) + "[base" + base + "]" ;
        }


    }
```

A postfix addition in the last method call in the recursive stack.

```
public static String getValueBase(int value, int base){

        int quotient = value / base;
        int remainder = value % base;

        if(quotient == 0 ){
            //Base case + Postfix
            return remainder + (base != 2 && base != 16 && base != 10) ? "[base"+base+"]" : "";
        }
        else
            // Another recursive call
            return getValueBase(remainder, base);


    }
```

Comment: thanks, but my assignment requires an in-method solution

Comment: Then you will need a third parameter to your method.public static String getValueBase(int value, int base, boolean postfix)

Comment: Updated with a postfix addition. Also, you have a lot of "magic numbers" in your solution that makes it prone to error. What if the value is a negative number?

Comment: the number is natural, i don\t have to account for negatives